# Editor with Maths functions

Tags: asp.net, wysiwyg

I am current working with student portal website. I need editor(e.g. fckEditor) with mathematical formula functionality like MS Word. These functionality contains inbuilt maths functions which can be taken by selecting them and also can be edited them into editor widow according to requirement. Also new functions will be added if required frequently.

Answer (score 1):

WIRIS makes a pluggin for fckeditor:

[WIRIS plugin for FCKeditor](http://www.wiris.com/plugins/docs/fckeditor)

[ASP.NET Demo](http://www.wiris.com/demo-aspx/pluginwiris/fckeditor_wiris/):

Answer (score 0):

Try some WYSIWYG editors [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor) and may be [here](http://www.mathjax.org/).